# Issue with Sculpting

Tags: mesh, sculpting

I've recently started to work with Blender as part of my job (head of my library's makerspace) but have been running into an issue when using the sculpt tools. They either don't work at all or when they do, even when I have the strength up to 100%, tools like crease or inflate have a very limited effect. I've double checked properties and watched a number of videos on YouTube but can't figure out what's going on. https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yz3tP.jpg

Quick note that I'm using a PC rather than a graphics tablet so I don't know if the fact I'm using a mouse rather than a stylus might be affecting anything. Anyway, if anyone has any ideas or tips for a total newbie, I'd really appreciate it!

Comment: Add one subdivision more, and mantain the wireframe overlay on until you get familiar with the tools. A pen is better than a mouse because of speed and pressure sensivity (a cheap model is enough, but it has to have pressure sensor), but you can also sculpt with a mouse.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I've actually made the levels viewport to 5 but the sculpt tool either doesn't work or still doesn't do a lot.

Comment: Save your work, and then apply the subdivision modifier and see if it works.

Comment: Ok, I just figured it out...I hadn't applied the subdivisions. Wow do I feel like an idiot! X D